# WMI - Where is IWbemClassObject::GetObjectText's WBEM_FLAG_NO_SEPARATOR flag defined?

Tags: wmi, definition, flags

MSDN says there are 2 flags you can pass to `IWbemClassObject::GetObjectText`, `WBEM_FLAG_NO_FLAVORS` and `WBEM_FLAG_NO_SEPARATOR`.

But I can't seem to find where they are defined. I tried googling them, but I can only find that NO_FLAVORS is equal to `0x1`. The only results for `NO_SEPARATOR` are the MSDN `GetObjectText` page (or verbatim copies on 3rd party sites). Does anyone know what it is?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa391448(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found this constant just doing a search in the win SDK, hope it helps.

WBEM_FLAG_NO_FLAVORS = 0x00000001

I didn't find the other, however.